# Error SQL server IRegistrationService not found

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

tengo un problema con sql server y management studio, al abrir una base de datos en ssms me da un error llamado iregistration service not found, tengo todo actualizado, he probado de todo, reparar  tanto sql server como ssms, reinstalar, activar y reactivar los servicios, generar otras instancias pero nada funciona, adjunto imagen del error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

aqui los detalles del error

===================================

No se encontró el servicio 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IRegistrationService' (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SDK.SqlStudio)

---

Ubicación del programa:

en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.ServiceProvider.GetService[T](IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.NavigationService.Initialize()
   en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.NavigationService.GetView(String urnPath)
   en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.d__11.MoveNext()
   en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.AddFields(List`1 list, IEnumerable`1 fields, IDictionary`2 allValidFields, AddFieldsFlags flags)
   en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.GetFields(INodeInformation source, Dictionary`2& allValidColumns)
   en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItemBuilder.BuildDynamicItemWithQuery(IList`1 nodes, INodeInformation source, INavigableItem sourceItem, String urnQuery, Boolean registerBuilder, Boolean registerBuiltItems)
   en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.IntegrationServicesNavigableItemBuilder.Build(IList`1 nodes, INodeInformation source, INavigableItem sourceItem, IFilterProvider filter)
   en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.NavigableItem.RequestChildren(IGetChildrenRequest request)
   en Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.ObjectExplorer.ExplorerHierarchyNode.BuildChildren(WaitHandle quitEvent)

Comment: Yo no me preocuparía de investigar mucho. Simplemente [reinstala el SSMS](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Lo hice ya 2 veces pero sigue igual, no sé de dónde puede venir ese problema

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!